# SpringBoot newbie. Trying to connect to a postgeSQL datasource (student database)

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

[image]
Every time I try to connect to the student database through IntelliJ, I am prompted for a password

if the password is empty I get a `null value for password` error, if I fill it in it says it's wrong

but as you can see on the left side of the screen I managed to connect through the shell.

I tried looking online for solutions and some say its an IntelliJ thing, but though some people can connect just fine without getting this error.

[edit] as requested, this is what in my pg_hba.conf, I screenshoted the bottom part, everything above is commented out.

[image]

Comment: Your code looks like it's connecting to the database and creating a table. What's in your application.properties?

Comment: You would have to show your `pg_hba.conf` file, point out which entry is relevant, show the error message in the PostgreSQL log, say if you set a password for the user, things like that. We cannot determine your problem from a screen shot.

Comment: This is my `application.properties` 

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true`

Comment: I've added the contents of my `pg_hba.conf` as a screenshot because the contents were too largs for a comment @NovaPenguin

Comment: @ThandoBhebhe Looks like your username is postgres and your password is admin. Did you try those credentials? Looks like your username is blank in intellij

Comment: @NovaPenguin I'm trying to accept your answer but I dont see the green tick, I dont know if its been removed? :/ (sorry, I'm  a total noob) But I want to give credit


Come to think of it, I dont think theres  a  way to accept a comment. Can you repost you comment  as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @ThandoBhebhe done! Glad that did it for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your username is Postgres and your password is admin. Did you try those credentials? Looks like your username is blank in IntelliJ.